# Javascript primitives

Tags: javascript, string, javascript-objects, primitive

Im still new to JS, learning about objects at the moment and a little confused on primitives. on W3schools a javascript primitive is defined as:

"A primitive value is a value that has **no properties or methods**.

A primitive data type is data that has a primitive value.

JavaScript defines 5 types of primitive data types:

string

number

boolean

null

undefined"

per: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp)

but isnt a string an object and has methods such as string.prototype.indexOf() and string.prototype.toUpperCase() those are considered methods right? What am i missing?

Comment: Avoid using W3Schols.

Comment: actually there are already `6` primitive types - `symbol` is the one you're missing here! - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is actually the difference between string and String. string is primitive but String is object.

```
var str = "string"  //primitive
var str1 = new String("string") //object
```

when you apply a method to str of String object class, it is automatically converted to the object.

**Auto-boxing** is the process whereby the JS will convert primitive data types to their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, string will be converted to String

Comment: In JavaScript “auto-boxing” is more commonly referred to as “coercing”.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript there are 5 primitive types: undefined, null, boolean, string and number. Everything else is an object. The primitive types boolean, string and number can be wrapped by their object counterparts. These objects are instances of the Boolean, String and Number constructors respectively.

Comment: There are 7 primitives in javascript (not 5 as you mentioned). These are; string, number, boolean, bigint, symbol, null and undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe because JavaScript automatically wraps those primitive values with an object. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive):

> Except for null and undefined, all primitive values have object equivalents that wrap around the primitive values:
>
> - String for the string primitive.
> - Number for the number primitive.
> - Boolean for the Boolean primitive.
> - Symbol for the Symbol primitive.

Comment: so then once the string is converted to an object, it is the "String" object wrapper that the method is performed on correct?